# iMac 2020 shuts down when I'm working in Photoshop or Bridge

Tags: imac, adobe, adobe-photoshop

I have new iMac 2020 with AMD Radeon Pro 5500 XT 8GB. I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7, Photoshop 2020 21.2.3 and Bridge 10.0.2.131. Are they 32-bit apps? I didn't know that. Sometimes when I work in Photshop or in Bridge it shuts down. After the restart it shows this error:

```
CPU Machine Check Architecture Error Dump (CPU: UNKNOWN, CPUID: 0x80000009000A0655)
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC3_STATUS=0xBE00000000800400
  IA32_MC3_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC3_ADDR=0xFFFFFF7F97C9D07A
  IA32_MC3_MISC=0xFFFFFF7F97C9D07A
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC4_STATUS=0xFE00000000800400
  IA32_MC4_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC4_ADDR=0xFFFFFF8013A590B3
  IA32_MC4_MISC=0xFFFFFF8013A590B3
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC11_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110A
  IA32_MC11_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC11_ADDR=0xFF71EC00
  IA32_MC11_MISC=0x43880000086
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC12_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110A
  IA32_MC12_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC12_ADDR=0xFF71CA00
  IA32_MC12_MISC=0x7880000086
Core: 0 
  IA32_MC13_STATUS=0xEE0000000040110A
  IA32_MC13_CTL=0x0
  IA32_MC13_ADDR=0xFF71CA40
  IA32_MC13_MISC=0x7880000086
```

Meanwhile, when I work in Final Cut with big and heavy files, effects etc. it never shuts down! What's wrong with Adobe? Can someone explain to me, please? How to fix it?

Update: I reinstalled all Adobe apps and for quite a while everything was fine until I tried to open several photos from Bridge into Photoshop today.
Here is the report:

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff016bf0cec): x86 CPU CATERR detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS version: 17P6610
macOS version: 19H15
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu Jun 18 20:30:46 PDT 2020; root:xnu-6153.145.1~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 828E8E47-4C82-3639-83B9-4F7DB86934F6
iBoot version: iBoot-5540.140.12
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x7
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x70604000400
PCIeUp link state: 0x89271611
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:     0x000000000ec24000
Kernel text base: 0xfffffff015c28000
mach_absolute_time: 0x44fd1007a74
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x5fa7493c 0x00039bfd
  Sleep   : 0x5fa74941 0x00065aa1
  Wake    : 0x5fa74941 0x000f2e00
  Calendar: 0x5faa4cd7 0x00023c5c

Panicked task 0xffffffe000448200: 2861 pages, 183 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe000714a90, backtrace: 0xffffffe015f534b0, tid: 318
          lr: 0xfffffff01647c860  fp: 0xffffffe015f534f0
          lr: 0xfffffff01647c6bc  fp: 0xffffffe015f53560
          lr: 0xfffffff016597770  fp: 0xffffffe015f53610
          lr: 0xfffffff016a495d8  fp: 0xffffffe015f53620
          lr: 0xfffffff01647c024  fp: 0xffffffe015f53990
          lr: 0xfffffff01647c37c  fp: 0xffffffe015f539e0
          lr: 0xfffffff0171ca974  fp: 0xffffffe015f53a00
          lr: 0xfffffff016bf0cec  fp: 0xffffffe015f53a30
          lr: 0xfffffff016be211c  fp: 0xffffffe015f53aa0
          lr: 0xfffffff016be4044  fp: 0xffffffe015f53b50
          lr: 0xfffffff016be1854  fp: 0xffffffe015f53be0
          lr: 0xfffffff016ba8cb8  fp: 0xffffffe015f53c10
          lr: 0xfffffff0169b6b14  fp: 0xffffffe015f53c50
          lr: 0xfffffff0169b6398  fp: 0xffffffe015f53c90
          lr: 0xfffffff016a54514  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What versions of macOS, Photoshop and Bridge do you have installed? The error mentions "IA32", are Photoshop and Bridge 32-bit apps (see https://www.macobserver.com/tips/how-to/macos-find-32-bit-apps/ for information on how to find out)?

Comment: I am using macOS Catalina 10.15.7, Photoshop 2020 21.2.3 and Bridge 10.0.2.131. Are they 32-bit apps? I didn't know that.

Comment: Well if Photoshop is the only app doing this then it is Photoshop & Bridge. I would uninstall and remove **ALL** of the Photoshop & Bridge support files/preferences and reinstall.

Comment: Photoshop and Bridge have been 64 bit apps for a long time - it's just their *installers* are 32 bit which is why they wouldn't work on Mojave or later.  Photoshop CC is fully compatible with Catalina.  If you're having difficulty, do as @SteveChambers said and uninstall and reinstall Photoshop.

Comment: I see that Photoshop and Bridge listed as 64-bit apps. In the same list, however, I found a bunch of Adobe 32-bit apps. Like AAM Registration Notifier, AAM Update Notifier, AAMLauncherUtil, Adobe AIR Application Installer, Adobe AIR Updater, Adobe Application Manager, adobe_licutil, ExtendScript Toolkit, KBRG_7_0, PHSP_18_0, PSTI_1_3_0, Save as Adobe PDF, Setup (in folder Adobe Application Manager), SwitchBoard, Uninstall Product (in folder Adobe Application Manager).

Comment: If I am going to uninstall Photoshop how to do this with all these 32-bit apps? Could it be that one of these apps is launching on the background and causes this shuts down?

Comment: Why are you hyper-focused on these 32 bit apps?  Get the correct installer for Photoshop and go from there.

Comment: Because Photoshop is 64-bit app and the error points at 32-bit and I see a bunch of 32-bit apps by Adobe. But I will try to reinstall it

Comment: The Photoshop[/CC installer SHOULD BE all you need. It **should** remove everything, including those dopey 32-bit apps still hanging around. Adobe is also known for having "special" uninstallers that removes every tiny little trace of an app anywhere on your Mac. Look for that.

Comment: I uninstall everything with Adobe Creative Cloud Cleaner and installed Photoshop and Illustrator. Once I launched Illustrator and clicked Create New Document it shut down my iMac. It also just before this gave me a warning that I have an old Wacom Driver. However, my driver is 6.3.15-3 (macOS 10.8 - 10.11) 12/21/2015 and it's the only driver Wacom has for Intous 3 tablets on their website. So, it's old and latest driver. I am not really sure if it's connected somehow. After this shut down I opened Illustrator several times and it was fine.

Comment: I've got new shut down today. See the update in the original post.

Comment: Trying to run 32bit code on Catalina wouldn't take down the whole computer! Worse case scenario the app would just crash. I don't know what's going on here, but I'm confident it has nothing to do with an app being 32bit.